# Adding multiple CC's using Zenpy

Tags: python, zendesk, zendesk-api

I am working on an automation script to push out emails based on tickets we receive from our CRM.

Is there a way for the collaborator_ids to take multiple emails? I've tried using email_ccs and email_ccs_ids with no luck. Below is what I am currently using to include one CC'd email address.

```
zenpy_client.tickets.update(Ticket(id=i.id, requester=User(email=roster_email, name=name), collaborator_ids=cc_email))
```

I've also tried: `collaborator_ids=(cc_email, cc_email2)`

Answer (score 1):

This will work (even if there are internal notes in the ticket):

```
# Add CC
url = "https://{sub}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/{id}"

payload = json.dumps({
  "ticket": {
    "email_ccs": [
      {
        "user_email": "new@email.com",
        "action": "put"
      }
    ]
  }
})
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Basic {token}',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response = requests.request("PUT", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

You could get the ticket ID from ZenPy like facetoe showed [here](https://github.com/facetoe/zenpy/issues/342):

```
ticket_audit = zenpy_client.tickets.create(Ticket(description='test', subject='test'))
print(ticket_audit.ticket.id) # Ticket ID of last created ticket
```

Comment: It will not work if there are any internal notes included in the ticket.

Comment: Yes, it worked with the internal note in ticket as well. Look at the updated answer.